# How to backup/export connections in network-manager in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, openvpn

If you have a number of configured wired/wireless or VPN connections in network-manager, how can you backup/export those connections together with the username/password (if you have VPN connections), so you can import them back on a new Ubuntu installation?

I've tried searching for answers to this but I cannot find anything anywhere.

I tried backing up the folder and connections within the folder `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` and then copying them on a different Ubuntu PC but I receive the error message:

```
read file: operation not permitted, not even for root
```

Comment: try this: copy `system-connections` folder in your new os.
and add your `username` to the connection files. like: `permissions=user:newusername:;`
and don't forgot to change the owner of files/folders like:
`sudo chown newusername /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`
.and if you still getting `permission error`, change the connections owner too.